# Problems with importing list of data from python to csv

Tags: python, csv, writer

I've just started using python, and I have some problems with exporting a list of data from python to csv.

I have some array of values, and each value corresponds to a specific time. What I want is copying these arrays (all have the same length) on a csv so that each row presents the value of all the variables for that specific instant of time. What I've written is:

```
with open ('Risultati.csv', 'w', newline='' ) as f:
    thewriter=csv.writer(f)
    
    thewriter.writerow(['x','y','z','w'])
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        thewriter.writerow(['x[%i]', 'y[%i]','z[%i]','w[%i]'])
```

but in the csv I've obtained in each row is `x[%i] y[%i] z[%i] w[%i]`.
I also would like that each list of values appears aligned with the header, like in a table with Excel.

I hope I made myself clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `thewriter.writerow(['x[%i]', 'y[%i]','z[%i]','w[%i]'])` seems wrong - try `thewriter.writerow([x[i], y[i], z[i], w[i]])`. However, it would be good if you can also share some data in the question so we can test the solution (and provide example desired output)

Comment: You need to clarify few things here. What is `x` here ?   What are `x,y,z,w` you are fererring to in the output??  The question is not so clear.

Comment: @urban It doesn't work.. I've obtain x[i] y[i] and so on.. The data that I want to import are the optimal values of variables obtained trough a  minimization problem using ortools

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
import csv
import random

x = random.sample(range(10, 30), 5)
y = random.sample(range(10, 30), 5)
z = random.sample(range(10, 30), 5)
w = random.sample(range(10, 30), 5)

with open ('out.csv', 'w', newline='' ) as f:
    thewriter=csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['x','y','z','w'])
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        thewriter.writerow([x[i], y[i], z[i], w[i]])
```

Gives you:

```
$ python3 ./test.py
$ cat ./out.csv
x,y,z,w
18,23,17,25
23,27,16,26
15,18,28,10
12,15,23,18
26,29,21,27
```

I would strongly recommend you read a tutorial on python lists! There are many out there, for example [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be possible to create pandas Dataframe and then save it to file at once?
Small example below:

```
import pandas as pd

# buffer for data
values = []
# here adding exemplary rows
values.append({'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3, 'w':4})
values.append({'x':4, 'y':5, 'z':6, 'w':7})
# convert to df
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
# save to csv
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @urban to the original post seems correct.

Still, I would advise you to take a look at the Pandas library (you will probably be using it at some point anyways).
You would only need:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()  # create a new empty DataFrame
df['x'] = x  # fill it with values
df['y'] = y
df['z'] = z
df['w'] = w
df.to_csv('.../file.csv', index=None)
```

Pandas also lets you use `df.to_excel()`, `df.to_parquet()`, and more, to save your output in other file formats.

Comment: I've obtain something like this 
 x y z w 
x[0] y[0] z[0] w[0]
x[1] y[1] z[1] w[1]

and so on... The data that I want to import are the optimal values of variables obtained trough a minimization problem using ortools, could this be the problem?

Comment: @Vale96 could you provide an example of x,y,z,w? It is a bit difficult to understand from your explanation.

Comment: I've found the error: my data are the results of an optimization problem so I had forgotten to add ```.SolutionValue()``` to my variables!

Comment: @Vale96 I am glad you solved your problem!
Please don't forget to accept whichever answer helped you most.